# sharepoint upload files by ruby

Tags: ruby, file, sharepoint, upload

I want to upload files into "Share Documents" by ruby script.

I tried "savon" to link sparepoint but it can't succeed.

" WSDL = "http://xxx.xx.com/sites/OK/Shared%20Documents" " is right?

" client.request.basic_auth "user", "userpasd" "

And it show a error message

'request': Savon::Client#request requires at least one argument (ArgumentError)

How to fix it and how to link/upload/download file from sharepoint by ruby script?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Look in the documentation for `Savon::Client#request` and see what arguments it needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and found the answer via google - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/savonrb/gq90FDuu77s/H7ip3VNnt0MJ

The provided answer:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
    wsdl.document = File.expand_path('../../../lib/wsdl/MI_TESTConnection_OutHTTP.wsdl', __FILE__)
    http.auth.basic "user", "password"
end
```

This is the actual code that worked for me:

```
client = Savon.client("http://path.to.my/service.wsdl") do
    http.auth.basic "user", "password"
end
```